# Itemize indentation problem inside a tcolorbox environment (Beamer)

Tags: beamer, itemize, tcolorbox

I want to modify itemize indentation inside a `tcolorbox` environment. At this moment it seems that TeX.stackexchange is not letting me upload an image of the problem, so i'll try to be clear.

I used:

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{%colback=red!5!white,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    colback=red!5!white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltext=black,
    title=#1}
```

to create a box for my presentation. The thing is that when I do, for example:

```
\begin{mybox}{Definition}
        \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
        \begin{itemize}
            \item The spectrometry ...
            \item spectrometers ...
        \end{itemize}
\end{mybox}
```

The result is a very large itemized items indentation inside the created box. I **do not** want to modify all my beamer itemize environments indentation, since I have a lot of them in plain text and they are just fine. So, I was wondering how can I just modify this certain environment (mybox). I tried a lot of things, including adding `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}`, or `\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}`, among others, with no exit at all. A MWE is shown below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\tcbuselibrary{skins,theorems}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{
    colframe=red!75!black,
    colback=red!5!white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltext=black,
    title=#1}
\usepackage{lipsum}    

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{itemize on text}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{itemize}
\item This is fine
    \begin{itemize}
    \item This is fine as well
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{mybox}{Definition}
        \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
        \begin{itemize}
            \item The spectrometry ...
            \item spectrometers ...
        \end{itemize}
\end{mybox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone knows how to get less indentantion space for this certain environment? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments only

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I already added a MWE to the question, thanks.

Comment: Concerning `enumitem`: That package is wonderful, but not compatible with `beamer`'s overlay mechanism, so never use it with `beamer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tcolorbox` default is some `left=...` value, so having a larger indentation than expected. In addition, there's the width of the left frame rule.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}
%\usepackage{booktabs} 

\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\tcbuselibrary{skins,theorems}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{
    colframe=red!75!black,
    colback=red!5!white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltext=black,
    left=0pt,
    title=#1}
\usepackage{lipsum}    

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{itemize on text}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{itemize}
\item This is fine
    \begin{itemize}
    \item This is fine as well
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{mybox}{Definition}
        \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
        \begin{itemize}
            \item The spectrometry ...
              \begin{itemize}
              \item spectrometers ...
              \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
\end{mybox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Woah.. it was quite easy. Thanks for your time @ChristianHupfer, works great.

Comment: @JorgeV: You're welcome. Please take a look on the `tcolorbox` manual -- it supports also `beamer's` `\only` overlay specification